# How to find max value in list datatype column in polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I am using a Polar data frame for the first time. I am trying to match input values with data in the Postgres table.
Sharing some sample code which is part of the actual code.
I have a column called "Score" of type list[i32]. As a next step, I am trying to find the maximum value in that list. I am getting errors.

```
import polars as pl
import jaro


def test_polars():
    fname='sarah'
    lname = 'vatssss'
    data = {"first_name": ['sarah', 'purnima'], "last_name": ['vats', 'malik']}
    df = pl.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
    df = (df.with_columns(
        [
            (pl.when(pl.col("first_name") == fname).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("E_FN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("last_name") == lname).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("E_LN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("first_name").str.slice(0, 3) == fname[0:3]).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("F3_FN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("first_name").map_elements(
                lambda first_name: jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(first_name, fname)) >= 0.8).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias(
                "CMP80_FN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("last_name").map_elements(
                lambda first_name: jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(first_name, lname)) >= 0.9).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias(
                "CMP90_LN"),

        ]
    )
    .with_columns(
        [ pl.concat_list(980 * pl.col("E_FN")  ,
                         970 * pl.col("E_LN") ).alias("score")



        ]
    )
    .with_columns(
        [pl.max(pl.col("score")).alias("max_score")

         ]
    )

    )

    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_polars()

C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Scripts\python.exe "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\polars data.py" 
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ first_name ┆ last_name │
│ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ str        ┆ str       │
╞════════════╪═══════════╡
│ sarah      ┆ vats      │
│ purnima    ┆ malik     │
└────────────┴───────────┘
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\polars data.py", line 45, in <module>
    test_polars()
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\polars data.py", line 34, in test_polars
    [pl.max(pl.col("score")).alias("max_score")
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\polars\functions\aggregation\vertical.py", line 175, in max
    return F.col(*names).max()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\polars\functions\col.py", line 288, in __new__
    return _create_col(name, *more_names)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\polars\functions\col.py", line 67, in _create_col
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: invalid input for `col`

Expected `str` or `DataType`, got 'Expr'.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`list.max()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.max.html) function. Simple example:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [[1, 8, 3],[6,2,7],[8,10,11]],
        "b": [4, 5, None],
    }
)

┌─────────────┬──────┐
│ a           ┆ b    │
│ ---         ┆ ---  │
│ list[i64]   ┆ i64  │
╞═════════════╪══════╡
│ [1, 8, 3]   ┆ 4    │
│ [6, 2, 7]   ┆ 5    │
│ [8, 10, 11] ┆ null │
└─────────────┴──────┘

df.with_columns(
    pl.col('a').list.max().alias('max_a')
)

┌─────────────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a           ┆ b    ┆ max_a │
│ ---         ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ list[i64]   ┆ i64  ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ [1, 8, 3]   ┆ 4    ┆ 8     │
│ [6, 2, 7]   ┆ 5    ┆ 7     │
│ [8, 10, 11] ┆ null ┆ 11    │
└─────────────┴──────┴───────┘
```

so in your case just use `pl.col("score").list.max` instead of `pl.max(pl.col("score"))`. [`max()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.max.html) is just a syntactic sugar for `col(names).max()` and supposed to return max value of the column, not max value of the list type cell of the column.